# Remove directories with a certain letter in their names

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I check if some directories include for example the letter **a** in Python, and delete them if so. This is my code using `shutil`. It checks to see if a directory is named `a` and removes it if it exists (and the sub-directories, etc.) but it doesn't delete a folder named `a7`:

```
import shutil

not_allowed = ["a", "b"]

for x in not_allowed:
    if x in not_allowed:
        shutil.rmtree(x)
```

How do I manage to do this?

Comment: You should probably start with storing the folder name in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import shutil

fileList = ["crap", "hest"]

not_allowed = ["a", "b"]

for x in fileList:
    for y in not_allowed
        if y in x:
            shutil.rmtree(x)
            continue
```

Answer (score 2):

Say that your directory name is stored in `dirname`:

```
for x in not_allowed:
    if x in dirname:
        shutil.rmtree(dirname)
```

Then again, I'd do it like this:

```
if any(x in dirname for x in not_allowed):
    shutil.rmtree(dirname)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import shutil

not_allowed = ["a", "b"]

basedir = '/tmp/dir_to_search_in/'

for d in os.listdir(basedir):
    if os.path.isdir(d) and any(x in d for x in not_allowed):
        shutil.rmtree(d)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

can be achieved with some simple list comprehension

```
paths = ['directory1','directory2','others']
forbid = ['j','d']

print [p for p in paths if filter(lambda x:x not in p,forbid) == forbid]
['others']
```